# ReactJS | Cannot get data on ComponentDidMount

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, axios, state

I am fetching data from a local Mock-API. The data that the server is sending have the following format:

```
module.exports = [
  {
    username: "george",
    email: "george@test.com",
    group: "foo",
    loggedIn: true
  },
  {
    username: "nick",
    email: "nick@test.com",
    group: "bar",
    loggedIn: false
  }
];
```

Basically, a list of Users as you can see. The unique I.D for each user is their `username`. In my ReactJS U.I, I have a list of users. When I click on one of the users, I get redirected to a new page, and the url, changes fine, depending on the of the user I clicked

But I cannot fetch any data regarding that user. I get an empty string printed with `JSON.Stringify`. This is my cocde:

```
/* eslint-disable react/prefer-stateless-function */
import React, { Component, Fragment } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

import PageHeader from './PageHeader';
import Breadcrumb from './Breadcrumb';
import Role from 'shared/common/enums/Role';

import { getUser } from '../../config/service';

class UserDetailsScreen extends Component {
  state = {
    inEditMode: false,
    user: {},
    error: null
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchUser();
  }

  fetchUser = () => {
    getUser().then(({ data }) => {
      this.setState({ user: data });
    });
  };

  render() {
    const {user } = this.state;
    return (
      <div className="container-fluid">
        <div><pre>{JSON.stringify(user, null, 2)}</pre></div>
        {user && (
          <Fragment>
            <Breadcrumb
              items={[
                {
                  name: 'Users',
                  url: 'users'
                },
                {
                  name: user.username,
                  url: `${user.username}`
                }
              ]}
            />
            <h1 className="heading-title">{user.username}</h1>
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default UserDetailsScreen;
```

The `getUser()`, is a function that listens on my local endpoint. This is the endpoint: `GET_USER: name =>`http://localhost:5000/api/user/${name}`,`.

And here is the `getUser()`:

```
export const getUser = name => {
  const options = {
    method: httpMethod.GET,
    url: endpoint.GET_USER(name)
  };
  return instance(options);
};
```

This is the Dyson Server instance for getting the Specific user with the username as a unique id:

```
const users = [
    {
    username: "george",
    email: "george@test.com",
    group: "foo",
    loggedIn: true
  },
  {
    username: "nick",
    email: "nick@test.com",
    group: "bar",
    loggedIn: false
  }
]

module.exports = {
  path: '/api/user/:username',
  method: 'GET',
  template: (pathParameters) => {
    return users.find((user) => {
      return user.username === pathParameters.username;
    })
  }
};
```

Do you see any mistake with it??

Comment: Put a breakpoint on fetchUser, inside the then , i am suspecting your API is not returning valid results.

Comment: You are right. It is printing this: `data = ""`

Comment: This is what I am getting on Network: `http://localhost:5000/api/v1/user/undefined`. Which is weird, considering the mock-server is returning everything correctly..

Answer (score 1):

You are not passing 'name' argument in your `getUser()`, try passing:

```
fetchUser = () => {
    getUser('USERNAME').then(({ data }) => {
      this.setState({ user: data });
    });
  };
```

Comment: You are not wrong. I tried that one. But how do i make it dynamic? Hardcoded values aren't an options. Also this should come from the table.row automatically, passed to the URL and to the page-Details..

Comment: so you may pass `table.row.USERNAME` as an argument to the function, i guess that would help.

Comment: I do this: `<Link
      to={{
        pathname: ``/users/${row.username}``
      }}
    >` and I get as arguments on a function. `const someName = (cell, row) => {}`